# How to use this example addClass and removeClass

Tags: jquery, css

This will remove the active class from thumbs class `addClass` active and another class are all `removeClass` active, but I don't know what to do.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".thumbgallery .thumb a").click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");

        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".largethumb img").attr("src",href);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      });
    });

      //html

<div class="largethumb">
         <img src="images/detail/ref.jpg"/>
         <a class="left" href="#"> <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right" href="#"> <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a> 
 </div> <!-- End largeImage -->

  <div class="thumbgallery clearfix">
     <div class="thumb active"><a href="images/detail/ref.jpg"><img src="images/detail/ref.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div class="thumb"><a href="images/detail/car2.jpg"><img src="images/detail/car2.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div class="thumb"><a href="images/detail/car3.jpg"><img src="images/detail/car3.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div class="thumb"><a href="images/detail/car4.jpg"><img src="images/detail/car4.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div class="thumb"><a href="images/detail/car5.jpg"><img src="images/detail/car5.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div class="thumb"><a href="images/detail/car6.jpg"><img src="images/detail/car6.jpg"/></a></div>                       
    <div class="thumb"><a href="images/detail/car1.jpg"><img src="images/detail/car1.jpg"/></a></div>
     <div class="thumb"><a href="images/detail/car6.jpg"><img src="images/detail/car6.jpg"/></a></div>          
   </div>
```

Comment: why do you `addClass('active')` and directly `removeClass('active')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, You want to apply 'active' class on clicked div and removed from others?

If yes, then you should use:

```
$(".thumbgallery .thumb a").click(function(e) {
      $('.thumb').removeClass("active");  //-- Remove "active" from all elements with "thumb" class     
      $(this).parent().addClass("active"); //-- Add class on clicked anchor tag's parent element
      var href = $(this).attr("href");
      $(".largethumb img").attr("src",href);
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dvks4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

With

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
$(this).parent().removeClass('active');
```

You add `active` class and remove it in the same time so there is no effect. Try with:

```
$(this).parents('.thumb').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ8ed/1/)

Comment: thank my friends about your answer. i like that my work.

Comment: @ကစၥပနဒီ If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it with the tick on the left.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $(".thumbgallery .thumb a").click(function(e) {
         $(".thumb").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
}
```

If you dont want active class of selected parent .you have to do like this

```
$(".thumbgallery .thumb a").click(function(e) {
             $(".thumb").addClass("active");
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
    }
```

Comment: @ကစၥပနဒီ . i need some clarification about your question ..who is need active class ...